# Find python lxml version

Tags: python, lxml

How can I find the installed python-lxml version in a Linux system?

```
>>> import lxml
>>> lxml.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dir(lxml))
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'get_include',
 'os']
>>>
```

Can't seem to find it

Comment: How did you install lxml?

Comment: using apt-get in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Could you please clarify in your question whether you wanted to get the ``lxml`` version from within Python programtaically?

Comment: @JamesMills I don't necessarily need to get programatically, just some way

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can get the version by looking at `etree`:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.LXML_VERSION
(3, 0, -198, 0)
```

Other versions of interest can be: `etree.LIBXML_VERSION`, `etree.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION`, `etree.LIBXSLT_VERSION` and `etree.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION`.

Answer (score 12):

I assume you want to determine `lxml`'s version programatically from Python. Since `lxml` does not provide this information via way of a *typilca* `__version__` attribute on the top-level package you will have to resort to using `setuptools`' `pkg_resources.require()` function:

```
>>> from pkg_resources import require
>>> match = require("lxml")
>>> match
[lxml 3.3.0beta1 (/home/prologic/lib/python2.7/site-packages)]
>>> lxml = match[0]
>>> lxml.version
'3.3.0beta1'
```

Answer (score 10):

Here are two more ways to do it, with minimal typing.  You could do it with pip from the command line:

```
$ pip freeze | grep lxml
lxml==3.2.5
```

Since you installed from ubuntu repository with `apt-get` you can also use dpkg:

```
$ dpkg -l python-lxml
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                     Version                  Description
+++-========================-========================-================================================================
ii  python-lxml              2.2.4-1                  pythonic binding for the libxml2 and libxslt libraries
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised that nobody suggested

`pip show lxml`

Comment: Ha! Beautiful. However, I guess not everyone is using `pip` as a installation method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pip` as well:

```
import pip
lxml_package = [pckg for pckg in pip.get_installed_distributions() 
                if pckg.project_name == 'lxml'][0] # assuming lxml is installed
print lxml_package.version
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from lxml import etree
etree.__version__
```